# Entity Framework exception: No suitable constructor found for entity type 'CultureInfo'

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I have this:

**model class**

```
public class BusinessSelectList
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsBusinessGroup { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; } = false;
}
```

**DbContext**

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbQuery<BusinessSelectList> BusinessSelectList { get; set; 

    /** other virtual DbQuery properties **/
}
```

**Repository**

```
public class BusinessRepository :IBusinessRepository
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpAccessor;
    private readonly AppDbContext _context;

    public BusinessRepository(AppDbContext context, IHttpContextAccessor httpAccessor)
    {
        _context = context;
        _httpAccessor = httpAccessor;
    }

    public IEnumerable<BusinessSelectList> GetAsSelectList()
    {
        var query = @"exec webApp.usp_Business_GetAsSelectList @user";
        var p1 = new SqlParameter("user", _httpAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
        return _context.BusinessSelectList.FromSql(query, p1).ToList();
    }
}
```

**Error**

> Entity Framework exception: No suitable constructor found for entity
>   type 'CultureInfo'

[image]

I tried to search for a solution, but I did not find any. What can be wrong here? :/

The full exception is:

```
{System.InvalidOperationException: No suitable constructor found for entity type 'CultureInfo'. The following parameters could not be bound to properties of the entity: 'name', 'name', 'useUserOverride', 'cultureData', 'isReadOnly', 'culture', 'culture', 'useUserOverride', 'cultureName', 'textAndCompareCultureName'.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConstructorBindingConvention.Apply(InternalModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ImmediateConventionScope.OnModelBuilt(InternalModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.OnModelBuilt(InternalModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.Model.Validate()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.CreateModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, IModelValidator validator)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<GetModel>b__1()
   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
   at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.GetModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, IModelValidator validator)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder.<>c.<TryAddCoreServices>b__7_1(IServiceProvider p)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_Model()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbQuery`1.get_EntityType()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbQuery`1.get_EntityQueryable()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalQueryableExtensions.FromSql[TEntity](IQueryable`1 source, RawSqlString sql, Object[] parameters)
   at MBPT.CoreWeb.Repository.BusinessRepository.GetAsSelectList() in C:\Users\czurbanlu\Source\Workspaces\Workspace\MBPT\MBPT.CoreWeb\MBPT.CoreWeb\Repository\BusinessRepository.cs:line 32}
```

Comment: Post the full exception, including the call stack. Somehow, somewhere an object with a CultureInfo is passed. You can get it easily with `Exception.ToString()`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you are right, I add it to the question, it seems as problem related to `InternalModelBuilder`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same error when I accidentally included a `DataTable` property in my entity class instead of a `DateTime`.

```
public class ActivityLog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Event { get; set; }
    public DataTable DateLogged { get; set; }   // Should have been a DateTime!
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Somewhere, it seems you have a property on one of your entities like:

```
public CultureInfo Foo { get; set; }
```

Since `CultureInfo` is a class, Entity Framework will treat it as an entity, and may even be creating a database table for it, depending on how your entity is set up. In either case, when it attempts to build your object graph, it's trying to fill this property in, but cannot because `CultureInfo` doesn't have a parameterless constructor.

Long and short, find where you've done this and remove it. If you need to somehow persist culture information, persist something you can use to get an appropriate `CultureInfo` instance later. You can't have it on your entity itself though.

Comment: thank you, but the point is, i am not using `CultureInfo` in model entities, i only setup `cultureInfo` in the `startup.cs` and if i comment it out, the error is the same :/

Comment: It's there somewhere. It might be in a related entity. Do a project-wide search for it.

Comment: okay, i did. i found it twice in ViewHelper class, twice in ViewModel classes, once in startup.cs and once in class which format xml, i dont see relation with a database yet. Its not used as a property but inside code of a methods.

Comment: The exception indicates it's seeing it as an entity, which means some how some where it's added as a relation. Keep digging is all I can say.

Comment: i found it ! the exception it thrown by `public virtual DbQuery<DataTable> DataTable { get; set; }` it is not even used ^.^

Comment: Thank you!. I had similar issues on my project and after spending hours wondering around, your suggestions helped me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 4):

I had this same problem as well. In my case I had a near empty data access layer project. The problem came and went as I created a navigation link to an entity type that is not available in the DbContext as a DbSet.

for example the code underneath gave the same problem OP had:

```
    public class Organization
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid OrganizationId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        // Navigation properties
        public virtual ICollection<Pipeline> Pipelines { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public MyContext()
        {
        }

        public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> dbContextOptions) : base(dbContextOptions)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Organization> Organizations { get; set; }
}
```

While this code didn't:

```
    public class Organization
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid OrganizationId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        // Navigation properties
 // COMMENTED OUT       public virtual ICollection<Pipeline> Pipelines { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public MyContext()
        {
        }

        public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> dbContextOptions) : base(dbContextOptions)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Organization> Organizations { get; set; }
}
```

The problem could be solved in two ways:

- out commenting the navigation link
- adding property `DbSet<Pipeline>` to the DbContext.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who runs into this issue and none of thecomments or solutions are resolving your issue, make sure your table entities are not inheriting from something that inherits from IDisposable (or potentially just not inheriting from System.Data.DataTable).

In my case, some tutorial I was reading (probably a little too quickly for my own good, to be fair) was inheriting "System.Data.DataTable". I was in "Try 200 things really quickly mode" and had forgotten I was inheriting it with one of my many table entities.

The error you get is very non-specific & vague, so hopefully this helps someone out there!